# how to set up log level by package at startup?

Tags: ros, ros2, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to configure the logging level associated to a package independently of the node or the executable it is located in?

For example. In ROS1 navigation stack I could develop a planner as a plugin that was loaded by move_base. I could in that case disable setup the log level of move_base to X and the log level of my planner to Y.

That was possible using the a configuration file such as the following:

```
log4j.logger.ros=INFO
log4j.logger.ros.roscpp.superdebug=WARN
log4j.logger.ros.move_base=INFO
log4j.logger.ros.myplanner=DEBUG
```

and referencing that file with the environament variable "ROSCONSOLE_CONFIG_FILE".

Is it possible to do something similar in ROS2? maybe passing some argument to the executable with ros nodes?

Note: Using `--ros-args --log-level INFO`  looks insufficent since looks like it cannot filter by package.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/366056/how-to-set-up-log-level-by-package-at-startup?/) by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2982 on 2020-11-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe this will be supported in Galactic Geochelone.

From the [(I guess *pre*) release notes](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Releases/Release-Galactic-Geochelone/) (specifically [here](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Releases/Release-Galactic-Geochelone/#ability-to-specify-per-logger-log-levels)):

> #### New features in this ROS 2 release
>
> **Ability to specify per-logger log levels**
>
> It is now possible to specify different logging levels for different loggers on the command line:
>
> ```
> ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker --ros-args --log-level WARN --log-level talker:=DEBUG
> ```
>
> The above command sets a global log level of WARN, but sets the log level of the talker node messages to DEBUG. The `--log-level` command-line option can be passed an arbitrary number of times to set different log levels for each logger.

It's likely the same functionality will then also be exposed by `launch_ros`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2